# Is it possible to provide default value for subscripting in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, default-value

In Matlab when one tries to access an element of a matrix that doesn't exist usually an error is raised:

```
>> month(0)
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

I was wondering whether there is a function that allows supplying default value in such cases. E.g.,:

```
>> get_def(month(0), NaN)
ans =
   NaN
```

P.S. I can workaround this particular case of subscript (`0`), but I was wondering about more generic way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in MATLAB function to do what you want. You *could* use a [try-catch](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/try.html) block:

```
>> try a = month(0); catch a = nan; end
>> a

a =

   NaN
```

However, the best option would probably be to error-check the index *first*, throwing an error or setting a variable to a default value if it is out of range.

If you really want to try using an index that may be 0, you could write your own `get_def` function. Here's one way to do it:

```
function value = get_def(vector,index,defaultValue)
  try
    value = vector(index);
  catch
    value = defaultValue;
  end
end
```

You would then use this function in the following way:

```
>> month = 1:12;
>> get_def(month,0,nan)

ans =

   NaN

>> get_def(month,1,nan)

ans =

     1
```

Comment: I'm just commenting to say that I love your icon.  Yay QOTSA!

Comment: @Matt: Thanks! You're only the second person to notice/mention it.

Comment: I just happened to be listening to a live QOTSA album when I stumbled on this.  Thanks for completing the sensory picture.

Answer (score 3):

An elegant solution would be to create a subclass of the builtin **double** MATLAB class and overload the **subsref** method:

```
classdef myDouble < double

    methods

        function obj = myDouble(val)
            obj = obj@double(val);
        end

        function val = subsref(obj, S)
            try
                val = subsref@double(obj, S);
            catch
                val = NaN;
            end
        end

    end

end
```

You could then use this class as follows:

```
>> a = myDouble(1:10);
>> a(1:3)

ans = 
  myDouble
  double data:
     1     2     3

  Methods, Superclasses

>> a('asdsa')

ans =
   NaN

>> a({1, 'asdf'})

ans =
   NaN
```

Since the subclass inherits from the **double** class, you still get all the functionality of the **double** class and the added functionality of your custom **myDouble** class.

Check out the MATLAB help on:

- [constructing subclasses](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brd2m9e-1.html#brd2m9e-6)
- the [subsref](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/index.html?/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/subsref.html) method

Comment: +1: I actually considered making this suggestion, but thought it might be a little more complexity than what the OP was looking for.

Comment: I hope the OP is encouraged to explore MATLAB classes.  You're correct that it may be more complex initially but solving problems using can become a lot easier even with a beginner's understanding of OOP concepts.  Of course, used inappropriately, programs can also become Rube Goldberg-ian!